# Can i restore more than one msgstore.db.crypt7 file in whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

1. Recently changed my old phone to new one (Samsung to MotoX). During this old to new phone conversion phase (for one month) I didnt use Whatsapp at all.
2. Before totally stopped using whatsapp on my old phone, I Had taken whatsapp database backup from my old phone.
3. But when I got my new phone, in a hurry I totally forgot about whatsapp backup (which i had taken from old phone) and installed whatsapp on my new phone.
4. As per process it's got created new msgstore.db.crypt7 (just for that one month, during I didnt use whatsaap at all) file in database folder of whatsapp on my new phone.
5. Then I recollected about old whatsapp backup file (from old phone), so i uninstalled whatsapp on my new phone, again took a backup of newly created msgstore.db.crypt7 (from new phone), rename it as msgstorenew.db.crypt7 and kept in the same database folder of new phone.
6. To get all the older whatsapp message, i have kept old backup file msgstore.db.crypt7 (from old phone) in database folder of new phone and reinstalled whatsapp again on new phone.
7. I successfully able to restore all my old whatsapp messages.
8. But now along with the old whatsapp messages, I want to restore newly created whatsapp backup file (for one month) as well which i renamed it as msgstorenew.db.crypt7 (in the same database folder), so that i can have all the messages (old+new). But i am not able to find any option for the same.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [wahtsapp faq](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20887921#further),

> Current chat history will be lost upon restoration.

Anyway, you could follow these steps.
*For every older conversation:*

1)Use the ["email conversation" function](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/23756533):

> To export a copy of the history of an individual chat or group, you
>   can use the Email Chat History feature:
>
> Tap and hold on the conversation or group. Select Email conversation
>   Choose whether to Attach Media or not. An email will be composed with
>   your chat history attached as a .txt document.
>
> If you choose to attach media, the most recent media sent will be
>   added as attachments.

2) Send the composed email to yourself.

After you did that for every older chat, restore the newer ones using your backup.
This way:

- You will be able to read your newer messages on whatsapp normally.
- You will be able to read your older messages opening the attached .txt file in the emails that were composed

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome to Android enthusiasts

Answer (score -1):

Install the latest version of WhatsApp from Google Play, then try restoring your backup. It fixed the issue for me.